# Can i rotate all objects without having to do it separately for every object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game where i rotate all objects with the same value. It would help me a lot if I could somehow rotate all objects without having to use the transform.rotate function on every object (transform is really inefficient). 
I was thinking of making the transform static but that doesn't seem achievable. I also can't place them in one object and move it since it would change their position. Do you have any advices? Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for the replies. My goal is to rotate the objects with the same value but not the common way.
I don't want to use the transform in every object.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, rotX);
    }
}
```

I want them to have the same transform.rotation with different transform.position and transform.scale. This way transform.Rotate() would only be used once, not the times of the number of objects. 
I want to avoid having to access the transform of every object.

Comment: how is transform.rotation inefficient? are your objects parented to each other?

Comment: Nope. transform is inefficient in general as specified by unity.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-scripts-unity-games

Comment: The article has told you set localRotation is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a more detailed example? When it comes to perfomance, it is really hard to tell which approach would be better in your case without a sample code.
Here you can find some insights about using the physics engine (using `RigidBody.MoveRotation()` ) to accomplish a better performance vs `Transform.Rotate`: https://answers.unity.com/questions/294452/rotation-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a `script` named controller .

There use `UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();`

Now you have an `array` of `GameObject`s. Use `foreach` or a loop and set `transform.rotation`.

Now you have all objects moving at once.

```
GameObject[] allObjects = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>() ;
foreach(object go in allObjects)
if (go.activeInHierarchy)
   print(thisObject+" is an active object");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that wouldn't achieve my goal since i'd still have to access the transform of every object (i edited the text, hopefully it's more understandable now)

Comment: If I am not wrong, then you are looking for prefab, are you ?